# Ruby on rails routes doesn't redirect me to the link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've been learning about Ruby on rails for... 4 days now? through a video on Youtube and everything was okay until tried to create links to modify the user information and log out from the session.
I installed **devise** and got the following routes. I created links for **new_user_session** and and **new_user_registration** and they work fine, but for some reason the links for **destroy_user_session** and **edit_user_registration** are not working.
Here is my code:

```
      <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>  
      <%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_registration_path %>
```

When I click on the link to sign out, I get the following error:
**No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"**

So even if I specified `method: :delete`, the error says the rout doesn't match the GET method?

In the case of **edit_user_registration**, I get redirected to the user/sign_up page. If I try to write the whole address in the search bar (like .../users/edit), it changes to users/sign_up.

I would really appreciate if somebody can help me because I'm totally lost right now...
Thank you in advance.

```
    rails routes
                                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                       Controller#Action
                        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                          devise/sessions#new
                            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                          devise/sessions#create
                    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                         devise/sessions#destroy
                       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                                     devise/passwords#new
                      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/passwords#edit
                           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#update
                                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#update
                                         POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#create
                cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                           devise/registrations#cancel
                   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                          devise/registrations#new
                  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                             devise/registrations#edit
                       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                                  devise/registrations#update
                                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                                  devise/registrations#update
                                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                                  devise/registrations#destroy
                                         POST   /users(.:format)                                                                                  devise/registrations#create
                                 friends GET    /friends(.:format)                                                                                friends#index
                                         POST   /friends(.:format)                                                                                friends#create
                              new_friend GET    /friends/new(.:format)                                                                            friends#new
                             edit_friend GET    /friends/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                       friends#edit
                                  friend GET    /friends/:id(.:format)                                                                            friends#show
                                         PATCH  /friends/:id(.:format)                                                                            friends#update
                                         PUT    /friends/:id(.:format)                                                                            friends#update
                                         DELETE /friends/:id(.:format)                                                                            friends#destroy
                              home_about GET    /home/about(.:format)                                                                             home#about
                                    root GET    /                                                                                                 home#index
        turbo_recede_historical_location GET    /recede_historical_location(.:format)                                                             turbo/native/navigation#recede
        turbo_resume_historical_location GET    /resume_historical_location(.:format)                                                             turbo/native/navigation#resume
       turbo_refresh_historical_location GET    /refresh_historical_location(.:format)                                                            turbo/native/navigation#refresh
           rails_postmark_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/postmark/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/postmark/inbound_emails#create
              rails_relay_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails(.:format)                                              action_mailbox/ingresses/relay/inbound_emails#create
           rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails#create
     rails_mandrill_inbound_health_check GET    /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#health_check
           rails_mandrill_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#create
            rails_mailgun_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime(.:format)                                       action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails#create
          rails_conductor_inbound_emails GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                          rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#index
                                         POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                          rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#create
       new_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/new(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#new
      edit_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id/edit(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#edit
           rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#show
                                         PATCH  /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                         PUT    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                         DELETE /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#destroy
new_rails_conductor_inbound_email_source GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources/new(.:format)                              rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources#new
   rails_conductor_inbound_email_sources POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources(.:format)                                  rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources#create
   rails_conductor_inbound_email_reroute POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/reroute(.:format)                               rails/conductor/action_mailbox/reroutes#create
rails_conductor_inbound_email_incinerate POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/incinerate(.:format)                            rails/conductor/action_mailbox/incinerates#create
                      rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs/redirect#show
                rails_service_blob_proxy GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                                  active_storage/blobs/proxy#show
                                         GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                                        active_storage/blobs/redirect#show
               rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations/redirect#show
         rails_blob_representation_proxy GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/proxy/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)    active_storage/representations/proxy#show
                                         GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)          active_storage/representations/redirect#show
                      rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                                       active_storage/disk#show
               update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                               active_storage/disk#update
                    rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)
```

Answer (score 1):

For rails versions up until (not including) 7, `method: :delete` would have been enough. I encountered the same issue you have in a new rails 7 project and it seems now you have to use `data: {turbo_method: :delete}`. Same goes for other non-GET requests, although you can also cheat a little with stuff like `button_to` which defaults to a POST-request.

EG:

```rb
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete }, class: "some-class" %>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your comment.
I added the data: {turbo_method: :delete} code, but it still doesn't work. If I manually change the address to users/sign_out, I keep getting the same error message as before: routing error, No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

Comment: I think we will need a tad more info, because this _should_ work out of the box. Are you using Rails 7? do you have turbo-rails and hotwire? how are your routes created?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like maybe you are missing the JavaScript to make the magic happen. Are you sure everything is included? Turbo is a JavaScript library that swoops in and turns that link into a post. It's not confusing or anything :D

https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#performing-visits-with-a-different-method